# Routing USB-C 2nd D+ D- Pair Using Through Hole Receptacle

Tags: pcb-design, usb, usb-c

Using a Molex Rt Angle USB-C Receptacle 2169890002. The 0.9mm spacing of 0.4mm holes does not allow signal traces placed between the pins. Will only be running USB 2.0 and really want to retain the USB-C plugs' bi-directional insertion functionality.

D+ signal is easy. D- is the problem. Best we could come up with is this routing. Any thoughts or ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

USB2.0 (implied: High Speed mode) operates at 480Mbps, or at typical 60% velocity factor, one bit-time (electrical length) is 375mm (physical length); a stub length of say 1/10th that or 37mm shouldn't be disastrous.

Mind that includes the pin length inside the connector itself, which you can't control, but is worse being a right-angle type (imagine the route the pins must take inside the body).

I wouldn't worry about it.

Personally, I might prioritize the `D-` route, and route the rest over the opposite layer -- stitching generously to ensure ground fill everywhere possible.  Something like this for a start:

[image: Modified D- route]

Note that `CCn` and `VBUS` are minimal priority signals (low bandwidth / DC), so can be routed circuitously if needed.

The `D+`/`D-` pairs don't need to be particularly "paired" (they couple much more strongly to GND than to each other), and most any mismatch or imbalance, on the order of the above length scale, makes little difference to signal quality anyway.  This probably can free up a bit of contention too.

A finer pitch fab process is also feasible; many budget proto services offer 4/4 mil design rules.  I forget offhand if typical USB-C pin spacings are enough for that to make the difference; just something to think about.

There are also hybrid SMT-THT connectors, which may permit routing underneath the pads.  These might not be available in this type of right-angle connector (I don't know offhand), but it may be an option for other projects.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.   Appreciate the info, thoughts and suggestions.